# How do I transition to a root on successful sign in using Ember-Auth?

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js

So I have successfully implemented Ember-Auth using a pure token based approach. I would like to redirect my user to the root of my app once they sign in.

I know I can use `actionRedirectable` (http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs in the docs) but since I am using a pure token approach and not storing anything in cookies I am effectively signing my user in again every time the page refreshes using a `remember_token` (which seems unideal but I'll work it out shortly). This means that using `actionRedireactable` would mean that I would be redirecting every time the user refreshes the page. Perhaps there is an anti-pattern in there somewhere?

Anyway here is my `SignInView`:

```
App.SignInView = Ember.View.extend({

  templateName: 'auth/sign_in',

  email:    null,
  password: null,

  submit: function(event, view) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    App.Auth.signIn({
      data: {
        email:    this.get('email'),
        password: this.get('password')
      }
    });
  }
});
```

If I call `this.get("controller").transitionToRoute('...')` directly after the signIn call then my user invariably isn't signed in by this point so they get redirected to the login page again. And if I try:

```
App.Auth.on('signInSuccess', function() {
  // ...
});
```

then I don't have any sensible way to access the router to do a transition. Any bright ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice you should not have logic in your view, logic is much better suited to live in controllers, so for your use case, create a `App.SignInController` an instrument there your authentication process:

### View

```
App.SignInView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'auth/sign_in',
  email:    null,
  password: null,

  submit: function(event, view) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var data = {
        email:    this.get('email'),
        password: this.get('password')
    }
    // forward the action to your controller passing along the
    // data object your sign in process needs
    this.get("controller").send("signIn", data);
  }
});
```

Furthermore, you should not transitionTo from elsewhere other than inside the router. By doing so, you could run into serious issues because you don't know in which `state` your router actually is. So the best thing to do is to get a reference to your router and call the `transitionTo` on the router instead:

### Controller

```
App.SignInController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  signIn: function(data) {

    // grab your passed data object and issues you sign in
    App.Auth.signIn({
      data: data
    });
    
    // subscribe to the `signInSuccess` event and 
    // then transition to your route but using 
    // the router itself
    App.Auth.one('signInSuccess', function() {
      var router = this.get('target.router');
      router.transitionTo('route_name');
    });

  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have tested, but I think that this works:

```
App.SignInView = Ember.View.extend({

  templateName: 'auth/sign_in',

  email:    null,
  password: null,

  submit: function(event, view) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var controller = this.get('controller');

    App.Auth.signIn({
      data: {
        email:    this.get('email'),
        password: this.get('password')
      }
    });

    App.Auth.one('signInSuccess', function() {
      controller.transitionToRoute('...');
    });

  }
});
```